# Llamar a la funcion de mi base de datos privada

Tags: php

Tengo un archivo llamado funciones.php, el cual tengo 1 clase y dentro de esa clase tengo 2 funciones. La primera función es la conexión con la base de datos y la segunda función un SELECT a la base de datos, como puedo llamar a la conexión de mi DB para que me ejecute bien la consulta?

```
    class MyClase {
        protected function accesoBD() {
            $usuario = "XXXXXXXX";
            $password = "XXXXXXXX";

            try {
                $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXXXXXXXXXX";
                $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $password);
                $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch (PDOException $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        public function getDesbloqueados() {
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM pruebas WHERE id = 0");
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $stmt->execute();
            $row = $stmt->fetchAll();

            return $row;
        }
    }
```

Muchas gracias!

===========================

Mi código actualmente

```
<?php

    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    class Myclase {
        protected $dbh;
        public function accesoBD() {
            $usuario = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
            $password = "XXXXXXXXXXX";

            try {
                $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXXXXXXXXXX";
                $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $password);
                $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch (PDOException $e){
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        public function getDesbloqueados() {
            $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM pruebas WHERE id = 0");
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $stmt->execute();
            $row = $stmt->fetchAll();

            return $row;
        }
}
```

Entonces yo voy a mi cliente.php que tengo lo siguiente:

```
   <?php
        $url = str_replace('clientew', 'serviciow', 'http://'.filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST').filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI'));
        $uri = str_replace('/clientew.php', '', 'http://'.filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST').filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI'));
        $cliente = new SoapClient(null,array('location'=>$url,'uri'=>$uri));

        // Llamamos a la funcion getDesbloqueados();

        $consulta = $cliente->getDesbloqueados();
        print_r($consulta);
    ?>
```

Finalmente en mi servicio.php tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php

    require_once('funciones.php');

    $uri = str_replace('serviciow.php', 'funciones.wsdl', filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST').filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI'));
    $server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri'=>$uri));
    $server->setClass('Myclase');
    $server->handle();

?>
```

Comment: A qué te refieres con bien? Este código te produce errores? De ser así agrega más descripción del problema a tu pregunta por favor

Comment: En la función getDesbloqueados(), necesito llamar a accedoDB para poder hacer la consulta @betaM

Answer (score 2):

Los puntos que creería debes cambiar son los siguientes:

- Declarar como propiedad de la clase a la variable `$dbh`
- Tus métodos deben ser de alcance `public` ya que si al que te conecta a la BD lo dejas como protegido te va a devolver un error de este tipo:

> Uncaught error: Call to protected method.....

lo anterior en razón de que los métodos y propiedades de tipo [`protected`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php) solo son alcanzados por la clase que los define y las clases que heredan de la cual los contiene, como este no es el caso entonces al momento de hacer la instancia el objeto vería como inalcanzable dicho recurso

- Si declaras a `$dbh` como propiedad de la clase entonces posterior deberás referirte a ella como `$this->dbn` para accederla
- Cuando hagas la instancia, el objeto debe acceder tanto al método que te conecta como al método de la consulta; de lo contrario te dará error de `null`

Propuesta:

```
<?php 

   class MyClase 
   {
        protected $dbn;
        public function accesoBD() 
        {
            $usuario = "XXXXXXXX";
            $password = "XXXXXXXX";

            try {
                $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=u562195257_morosos";
                $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $password);
                $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch (PDOException $e){
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        public function getDesbloqueados() 
        {
            $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM pruebas WHERE id = 0");
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $stmt->execute();
            $row = $stmt->fetchAll();

            return $row;
        }
    }

$conexionUno = new MyClase;
$conexionUno->accesoBD();
var_dump($conexionUno->getDesbloqueados());
```

Comment: Call to a member function prepare() on null in, me tira lo siguiente :/

Comment: @MiguelÁngelMartín edita tu pregunta y agrega el código donde estás haciendo la instancia de la clase, pues yo probé este ejemplo en local y funciona bien

Comment: $consulta = $cliente->getDesbloqueados(); así es como lo llamo

Comment: Entonces es la única clase y haces instancia de esta misma para acceder al método getDesbloqueados?

Comment: Sí, es la única clase que tengo

Comment: @MiguelÁngelMartín revisa la edición

Comment: ME tira error aqui :/ $conexionUno = new MyClase;
$conexionUno->accesoBD();

Comment: Que error te da ?

Comment: Si lo llamo desde el mismo archivo funciona de escandalo, pero intento llamarlo desde otro archivo y nada :/ podrías ayudarme a través del chat?

Comment: En el otro archivo haces require?

Comment: Es un poco raro xk estoy usando SOAP

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta cómo tienes el código del archivo  tratas de usar está clase y que te genera fallo

Comment: Ahí lo edité muchas gracias Y.Y

Comment: Lo siento me quedo corto entonces para poder ofrecerte una respuesta, esperemos alguien mas nos apoye con esta duda